# DeadLock - Two Process Locked Same Index

Tags: sql-server, index, locking, deadlock, lock-escalation

We have met a scenario that two process acquired exclusive lock on same index ans the same time two are requesting for shared lock to other process which eventually leads to dead lock.

I am still not sure how come **Select Statement acquires exclusive lock**!!

[image]

DeadLock XML ::

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="processcfb7c48108" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="processcfb7c48108" taskpriority="0" logused="9916" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057622872653824 (a18bb75a63b4)" waittime="2255" ownerId="34534941558" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-11-23T20:33:11.730" XDES="0x105204209f0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="22" kpid="11192" status="suspended" spid="145" sbid="4" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2018-11-23T20:33:11.730" lastbatchcompleted="2018-11-23T20:33:11.727" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.727" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Host1" hostpid="8916" loginname="User1" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="34534941558" currentdb="8" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname=".dbo.UpdateBatch" line="39" stmtstart="3958" stmtend="4692" sqlhandle="0x030008002e480353103ba4008fa4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
        <frame procname="dbo.ProcessRequest" line="1110" stmtstart="129114" stmtend="129204" sqlhandle="0x03000800a5eed57fbf40180090a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf />
    </process>
    <process id="process160dec204e8" taskpriority="0" logused="11924" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057622872653824 (09d0c04e1297)" waittime="977" ownerId="34534939320" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-11-23T20:33:11.640" XDES="0x5d8982a3b0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="3" kpid="16588" status="suspended" spid="355" sbid="4" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2018-11-23T20:33:11.640" lastbatchcompleted="2018-11-23T20:33:11.640" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.640" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Host1" hostpid="8828" loginname="User1" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="34534939320" currentdb="8" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname=".dbo.UpdateBatch" line="39" stmtstart="3958" stmtend="4692" sqlhandle="0x030008002e480353103ba4008fa4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
        <frame procname="dbo.ProcessRequest" line="1110" stmtstart="129114" stmtend="129204" sqlhandle="0x03000800a5eed57fbf40180090a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf />
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057622872653824" dbid="8" objectname="dbo.Batch" indexname="IX_Batch" id="lock84224bdc80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057622872653824">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process160dec204e8" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processcfb7c48108" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057622872653824" dbid="8" objectname="dbo.Batch" indexname="IX_Batch" id="lock1328943c100" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057622872653824">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processcfb7c48108" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process160dec204e8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Deadlock Graph for the Reference

[image]

Additional Code Block

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT b.Shop FROM [Batch] b
        INNER JOIN [Process] o ON o.procNo = b.procNo           
        WHERE b.Ship = N'P'             
    ) B)
    UPDATE b4 SET StringVal3 = (
            SELECT TOP 1 Shop FROM (
                        SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
                        SELECT b.Shop FROM [Batch] b
                            INNER JOIN [Process] o ON o.procNo = b.procNo           
                            WHERE b.Ship = N'P' 
                ) B)
        FROM [Batch] b4 WHERE b4.Ship = N'P' AND b4.Unique = 0 AND b4.Flag = 4
```

Comment: Why don't you include the complete deadlock graph as xml here? We want to see also the RESOURCES section of the graph, not only PROCESSES

Comment: this is the XML i have . I am not sure what exactly you are looking for !

Comment: You need to include the actual XML - not a screenshot.

Comment: Can you post it please as a text and not as a picture? And the complete text of your proc also, we cannot see any modification in your code, but it is presented

Comment: Screenshot has the whole xml content!

Comment: Yes it contains the resource list also but it's difficult to read it when it's picture, resource list is in the same row where processes list ends, can we have the graph as a text?

Comment: Show us at least the whole query. I guess there is an update statement on the table "Batch" after the if condition, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it has update statement , but Deadlock says It acuqires X-lock and waiting for S-lock !

Comment: >>>I am still not sure how come Select Statement acquires exclusive lock<<<It is not a SELECT to acquire X-lock but the UPDATE

Comment: You should show  the exact statement and not the half. Your statement cannot pass parsing because your IF is incomplete. Be sure that while one instance of your proc makes an update, another instance of this proc COUNTS the rows in the same table